# C# Custom MSBuild task fails when it depends on a project and uses a class from there

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, msbuild-task

I am trying to write a custom msbuild task to be used during the build of another solution.

I ran into the following problem.

- Writing a custom task that uses *no* dependency on another project works, another solution can use it and it works fine.
- Writing a custom task that uses a dependency of another project (in the same solution), can be built and packaged as NuGet package fine as well. But when used from another solution, it fails. The task *runs*, but *fails* to find the dependency it tries to use (the other project).

As far as I can tell it was installed successful in both cases.

The exception looks like the following:

```
ConsoleAppUsingTaskWithDependency/AnotherSimpleApp/AnotherSimpleApp.csproj(15,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SomeProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have created a simple reproduction scenario, with both tasks (and both solutions using each respective task) in github. This allows you to check the code and see what happens exactly. Please see: https://github.com/martin9998/msbuild-customtask-issue

I hope someone that knows about custom msbuild tasks can have a look and tell me whether I am missing something obvious in the setup, or that this is perhaps a bug?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Some resources to read: https://josef.codes/dotnet-pack-include-referenced-projects/
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891?ref=josef.codes

Comment: Spent an hour on this and did not figure how. I think the issue is related to current `dotnet pack` is not allowing to include references (as mentioned in links in above comment) and you would need to use `nuget.exe pack` , but that does not work with the .NET 6.0 SDK.

Comment: Thank you for looking and thanks for the links. In my case both are nuget packages (you can see that in the artifcact-dependency directory). Both are installed  (the dependency implicitly), you can use the dependency directly from the console program if you want. Without the dependency project artifcact, the task cannot be installed.

So is this still the same problem as specified at the links or is it slightly different, I wonder as both are nuget packages?